# Asp.net health monitoring all http requests

Tags: asp.net

HI,
If I want to have log of all requests made within a web site including any http bad requests, is this possible?
For e.g I want to be able to see if every http request from the site including any for images that don't exist etc.
All the things an IIS log has.
Is this possible with HTTP Module or something like the ASP.net Health monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the IIS configuration to let asp net engine to process all files, including static ones, this is not very practical. If you do this you could create and HTTPModule to intercept ANY request.

Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I was thinking when hosting a website with a hosting provider, not going to have access to IIS logs so wanted something else to do it.